# Evaluation of this double infinite summation

Tags: evaluation, summation

I want to evaluate the following double summation

```
Sum[(-1)^(i + j + i*j)*Exp[-Pi/2*( i^2 + j^2)], {i, -Infinity, 
  Infinity}, {j, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

I am really new both in using Mathematica and in doing mathematics using computer. I don't know if there is some special technics to deal with these kind of summations (Lattice sums) in Mathematica.

When I evaluate the former expression, Mathematica refuses to evaluate it and just reprint it in the output.

Theoretically, the expected value is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Mathematica***

You can try out numerical summation `NSum`,

```
NSum[(-1)^(i + j + i*j)*Exp[-Pi/2*(i^2 + j^2)], {i, -Infinity, Infinity},
 {j, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

which after some warnings gives an output,

> -2.22045*10^-16 - 1.04284*10^-68 I

If we increase the `WorkingPrecision`, will be able to get the desired result,

```
NSum[(-1)^(i + j + i*j)*Exp[-Pi/2*(i^2 + j^2)], {i, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
{j, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

> 0.*10^-30

```
Rationalize[%]
```

> 0

As suggested by @AccidentalFourierTransform, we "can use the option, `Method -> "AlternatingSigns"` to speed up the computation and remove the warnings".

**Maple**

Maple's `sum(sum(f(k,l), k=m..n),l=m..n)` command is able to directly compute the double sum,

```
restart:
Sum(Sum((-1)^(i + j + i*j)*exp(-Pi/2*( i^2 + j^2)), i=-infinity..infinity),
 j=-infinity..infinity);
evalf(%)
```

> 0

Comment: Thank you both for the quick feedback. Now using the numerical approach, is there a way to test if the actual limit is 0?

Comment: @AymaneFihadi What you mean by actual limit?

Comment: @ As I mentioned in my question, the limit of the above series is 0. I want to test that using Mathematica. By your valuable answer, we get that the limit value is around 0, as far as I understand there is possibly a way to make sure that this limit is actually 0 ?

Comment: @AymaneFihadi `Rationalize[0.*10^-30]=0`. BTW, Maple also gives zero.

Comment: OK, Thank you very much. I will tag this answer as Accepted later, in the hope if there is some other insight concerning doing lattice sums in general.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to do this sum in MA. Let us look at the function and its domain:

```
fig1 = MatrixPlot[Table[(-1)^(i + j + i j) Exp[-Pi/2*(i^2 + j^2)], {i, -10, 10}, {j, -10, 10}]];
fig2 = MatrixPlot[ Table[(-1)^(i + j + i j) , {i, -10, 10}, {j, -10, 10}]];
fig = GraphicsRow[{fig1, fig2}]
```

[image]

This suggests to split the sum as follows:

```
r1 = Sum[Exp[-Pi/2*((2 ki)^2 + (2  kj)^2)], {ki, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kj, -Infinity, Infinity}]
(*EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-2 Pi)]^2*)
r2 = Sum[Exp[-Pi/2*((2 ki + 1)^2 + (2  kj + 1)^2)], {ki, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kj, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 (*EllipticTheta[2, 0, E^(-2 Pi)]^2*)
r3 = Sum[Exp[-Pi/2*((2 ki)^2 + (2  kj + 1)^2)], {ki, -Infinity, Infinity}, {kj, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 (*EllipticTheta[2, 0, E^(-2 Pi)] EllipticTheta[3, 0, E^(-2 Pi)]*)
```

At the end we can numerically verify a nice identity between the elliptic functions

$\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-2 \pi }\right){}^2-\vartheta _2\left(0,e^{-2 \pi }\right){}^2-2 \vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-2 \pi }\right) \vartheta _2\left(0,e^{-2 \pi }\right)=0$

```
  N[r1 - r2 - 2 r3]//Chop
  (*0*)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, This is a nice idea. when I was trying to calculate this by pen, I was doing the same splitting of the lattice. btw when I said its theoretically 0, they link it with sigma of Weierstrass, and use some sophisticated argument, it is not direct.

Comment: From formula 8 and 14 [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticLambdaFunction.html), we find that $$\frac{\vartheta _2\left(0,e^{-2 \pi}\right)^2}{\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-2 \pi}\right)^2}=3-2\sqrt 2$$ With this, the last identity in this answer can be easily verified.

Comment: @J.M.issomewhatokay. Nice find !